# Detecting Lightning User Experience

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, userinfo

This [Salesforce Documentation](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages) suggests that we can detect which User Interface is being displayed by using the `$User.UITheme` and `$User.UIThemeDisplayed` global variables and the `UserInfo.getUiTheme()` and the `UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed()` Apex methods. In my org, I have enabled the Lightning experience for my user and switched over to the new UI. However, when I try to detect the interface using either in Visualforce using the global variables on through the Developer Console using the Apex methods, it keeps returning 'Theme3' and not 'Theme4d' as is expected. Has anyone else run into this issue? Are there more steps to Enable Lightning that I'm missing?

Comment: I know getUiTheme() return the "preferred" theme. But getUiThemeDisplayed must display the current one? Otherwise you could check if sforce.one is available in Javascript.

Comment: This was user error. I had Lightning Enabled, but I was checking the $User.UITheme and $User.UIThemeDisplayed whiled in Classic Mode.

Comment: @SuryatejMukkamalla Do you want to answer your own question with a description of what the problem was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just user error on my part. Although I had Lightning enabled, I had not switched to it when I was trying to detect the UI Theme. Once I switched to the Lightning view, it was detecting the UI Theme correctly.